# Minimal value of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I do not know the following statement is true or not:

Given $1<x_0<2$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any n, define  $A=\{ f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i\}$ where $a_i\in\{0\,,1\}$, then for any $f\,,g \in A$ and their degrees are the same, we have $\delta\leq|f(x_0)-g(x_0))|$ or $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$

Comment: yes, actually, I need the uniformly discrete in the sense of $\delta≤|f(x)|$

Comment: $a_i$ should be different.

Comment: because in my research, I need $a_i$ to be different.Otherwise, it is trivial.

Comment: I reedit it now

Comment: Now, I think that the problem is clear.

Comment: I think your question amounts to: given $1<x_0<2$ is it (always or sometimes?) true that $\inf(\{\,|\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^n| : n\in\Bbb N,a_0,\ldots,a_n\in\{-1,0,1\}\,\} \setminus\{0\})=0$? If that is the question, why not formulate it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0$ be a real root of the polynomial $1-X^2-X^3+X^4$ in the interval $(1,2)$; it exists by the intermediate value theorem because this polynomial has value $0$ and derivative $-1$ at $X=1$, and value $5$ at $X=2$. Then with $f(x)=1+x^4$ and $g(x)=x^2+x^3$ one has $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$, so no positive $\delta\leq|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|=0$ can exist.

I might add that the fact that you get answers that are looking at cases where $f(x_0)-g(x_0)=0$, it is because obviously this is precisely the only thing that can prevent $\delta$ from existing, so the whole formulation with $\delta$ seems a bit pointless.

Comment: In my research, I need f and g have the same degree. thank you  for your comment.

Comment: Well, nothing prevents you from adding a large degree monomial to both $f$ and $g$. I think you should start thinking: what condition could prevent $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in(1,2)$. The kind of conditions you are giving do not seem to do that.

Comment: I have edited my question